# двойное срабатывание скрипта в IE

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, уважаемые форумчане! Подскажите пожалуйста, может я чего не вижу.
В общем есть скрипт:

```
function clickCreateButton() 
{
var form = $('#object_html_form');
form.append("<INPUT type=hidden name=create_button value=\"Создать\">");
document.forms['object_form'].submit();
form.submit();
return false;
}
```

почему - то везде он срабатывает один раз, а в IE дважды. В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас дважды сабмит, какого поведения вы ожидаете? :)

```
document.forms['object_form'].submit();
form.submit();
```

Comment: да, я что-то совсем замылился, даже не увидел)) Пора на отдых) Спасибо Вам огромное)

Comment: @Денис не за что :)